# Slow upload on PoE AP on long flat cable run

Tags: networking, cat6, power-over-ethernet

I have [this Open Mesh AP](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01E7FO810) on [this flat 100' cable](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00WD017BG), powered via 802.3af PoE. I'm getting 55 mbps download speeds, but only 0.5 mbps upload speeds (should be around 10 mpbs up), testing on speedtest.net. If I plug my computer into the cable, I get 10 mpbs up as expected. I wondered if the PoE was interfering with the upload speed somehow, so I plugged in a PoE-powered IP phone and plugged my laptop into the Ethernet passthrough-port on the phone, but I'm still getting 55 down and 10 up. I plugged the AP into a different cable, and started getting 55 down and 10 up. I only get the slow upload speeds with that combination of cable and AP.

My current theory is that the switch has enough power to send a signal to the AP, but AP is not getting enough power from the switch to send a strong return signal. Since my laptop does not receive power via the cable, it is not affected. Is there any merit to this idea? Would it help if I used a 50' cable instead of a 100' cable?

Or is this problem intrinsic to using flat Ethernet cable instead of regular round Ethernet cable?

Comment: You better read [this](http://superuser.com/questions/836641/can-cable-be-the-cause-for-slow-upload-speed-but-not-the-download?rq=1)

Comment: @AmirHossein Thanks, but it's not quite related. Other devices have no trouble achieving fast upload speeds on that cable. Only the AP has trouble.